# Sunspot / Solr / Rails: Model Associations are not updating in the Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I have a Fieldnote model in my app, which has_many :activities attached to it through a table called :fieldnote_activities. I then define a searchable index this way:

```
searchable :auto_index => true, :auto_remove => true do
  integer :id
  integer :user_id, :references => User

  integer :activity_ids, :multiple => true do
    activities.map(&:id)
  end

  text :observations
 end
```

And then I have a Search model to store / update searches. The search model thus also has its own associations with activities. I then perform my searches like this:

```
@search = Search.find(params[:id])
@query  = Fieldnote.search do |query|
  query.keywords  @search.terms

  if @search.activities.map(&:id).empty? == false
    query.with    :activity_ids, @search.activities.map(&:id)
  end

end
@fieldnotes = @query.results
```

Now this all works GREAT. The problem is that if I change which activities that are associated with a fieldnote, the search results do not change because it appears the indices for that fieldnote do not change. I was under the impression that the :auto_index => true and :auto_remove => true flags when I define the searchable index would keep track of new associations (or deleted associations), but this appears not to be the case. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right that `:auto_index` and `:auto_remove` don't apply to associated objects, just the `searchable` object they are specified on.

When denormalizing, you should use `after_save` hooks on the associated objects to trigger a reindex where necessary. In this case, you want changes to the `Activity` model *and* the `FieldnoteActivity` join model to trigger a reindex of their associated `Fieldnote` objects when saved or destroyed.

```
class Fieldnote
  has_many :fieldnote_activities
  has_many :activities, :through => :fieldnote_activities

  searchable do
    # index denormalized data from activities
  end
end

class FieldnoteActivity
  has_many :fieldnotes
  has_many :activities

  after_save :reindex_fieldnotes
  before_destroy :reindex_fieldnotes

  def reindex_fieldnotes
    Sunspot.index(fieldnotes)
  end
end

class Activity
  has_many :fieldnote_activities
  has_many :fieldnotes, :through => :fieldnote_activities

  after_save :reindex_fieldnotes
  before_destroy :reindex_fieldnotes

  def reindex_fieldnotes
    Sunspot.index(fieldnotes)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I actually ended up using `after_destroy` (otherwise it would re-index with the association still intact), and instead of doing Sunspot.index(fieldnotes) I wrote a private method in the FieldnoteActivity model that simply did `fieldnote.index!` (i.e., re-index one field note rather than all of them). Thanks for putting me on the right path!

Comment: The correct way to do this is by making an `around_destroy` callback because in the before_destroy reindexing will have no effect as the Activity will not have been deleted yet. In the after_save, the association will be empty so no Activities will be reindexed! so in the around_destroy, grab the activities then yield, then reindex those activities.

Comment: can i ask how to reindex if i have a polymorphic?