# Sunspot ActiveRecord save doesn't reindex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot

I am new to Sunspot, based on their wiki https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.

```
"If you are using Rails, objects are automatically indexed to Solr as a part of the save callbacks."
```

But this doesn't work for me when calling save on the object, I had to manually run Object.reindex to be able to find the record in the search result. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Console log

```
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "toons" ("author", "created_at", "flag_id", "icon_s3_path", "json", "name", "state", "toon_type", "updated_at", "user_id", "uuid", "view_count") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["author", "2333333"], ["created_at", Thu, 15 Aug 2013 22:49:40 UTC +00:00], ["flag_id", nil], ["icon_s3_path", nil], ["json", "[json]"], ["name", "2222222"], ["state", "created"], ["toon_type", "animation"], ["updated_at", Thu, 15 Aug 2013 22:49:40 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 2], ["uuid", "2111112222"], ["view_count", nil]]

SOLR Request (25.6ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x007fc37bb71920> parameters={data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><add><doc><field name="id">Toon 21</field><field name="type">Toon</field><field name="type">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field name="class_name">Toon</field><field name="created_at_d">2013-08-15T22:49:40Z</field><field name="name_text">2222222</field><field name="author_text">2333333</field></doc></add>, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: , retry_503: , retry_after_limit: } ]

SOLR Request (2.9ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x007fc37bb71920> parameters={data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><add><doc><field name="id">Toon 21</field><field name="type">Toon</field><field name="type">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field name="class_name">Toon</field><field name="created_at_d">2013-08-15T22:49:40Z</field><field name="name_text">2222222</field><field name="author_text">2333333</field></doc></add>, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: , retry_503: , retry_after_limit: } ]

(7.5ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Can you show relevant logs? There should be someting logged when `save` is called.

Comment: Ok, now paste (maybe as gist or on pastebin, it will be a lot of text) what shows in `log/sunspot-solr-development.log` or whatever it is called in your app, now we know something is sent to solr, we must see what solr is doin with that ;)

Comment: BTW, is this an association? If so, check that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138557/sunspot-solr-rails-model-associations-are-not-updating-in-the-index

Comment: Its not association. gist: https://gist.github.com/jianbo/6245899

Comment: I found one line which worries me, you have turned off autocommit, is it done by purpose? If yes, then you should commit all changes manually (or rather by some other process). If not, please add that line to `config/sunspot.yml`: `auto_commit_after_request: true`, restart solr and check again.

Comment: Hi, its not working, this is my sunspot.yml https://gist.github.com/jianbo/6246206, and restarted solr bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop and bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start, and Rails server, missing anything?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35558/discussion-between-user1883793-and-zrl3dx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding auto commit into solrconfig.xml

```
<autoCommit> 
  <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs>
  <maxTime>20000</maxTime>
</autoCommit>
```

Comment: Off topic, but I had a similar problem and my issue wasn't Sunspot/Solr, but rather model caching. Just a heads up incase someone is caching and doing searches.

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed any re-indexing at all for solr? Anytime you change the searchable block in your model (including when you first create it), you need to call

```
rake sunspot:reindex
```

It will then ask you "are you sure", and mention some warnings about having a lot of data can take a long time. Reply 'y' and it will reindex all of your data according to the solr schema and your searchable blocks. After that, it should index automatically as you add data to the database. Remember to use the rake command anytime you change the searchable blocks though.